# What was Rand Paul's argument for objecting to the 2017 Montenegro Treaty?

Tags: united-states, senate

[In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pq3YdA4Mb84) John McCain says Rand Paul, a US Senator, is "working for Putin". I have a few questions about this:

- Did the treaty pass with bipartisan support?
- Did Rand Paul explain his reasoning for objecting to the treaty?
- If not, what political arguments were there against the treaty in general?

Comment: This question could give a bit more context. Maybe quickly explain "the treaty" and maybe also a longer quote from that video in which John McCain calls Rand Paul something, if it is related to the matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Did the treaty pass with bipartisan support?

Yes. Protocol to the North Atlantic Treaty of 1949 on the Accession of Montenegro was [ratified](https://www.congress.gov/treaty-document/114th-congress/12) by the US Senate. The vote was 97 - 2 ([roll call on senate.gov](https://www.senate.gov/legislative/LIS/roll_call_lists/roll_call_vote_cfm.cfm?congress=115&session=1&vote=00098)).

Rand Paul (R-KY) and Mike Lee (R-UT) voted "Nay". John Isakson (R-GA) abstained.

> Did Rand Paul explain his reasoning for objecting to the treaty?

Yes, he published an op-ed on time.com: [Sen. Rand Paul: Montenegro Joining NATO Is Against U.S. Interests](http://time.com/4718958/montenegro-nato-rand-paul/). In general, Sen. Paul was against expanding financial and military commitments of the US to NATO:

> Adding a country with fewer than 2,000 soldiers to NATO is not in our self-interest. There is no national security interest that an alliance with Montenegro will advance. If we invite Montenegro into NATO, it will be a one-way street with the U.S. committing to defend yet another country.

He also claimed that the Treaty is mainly a political gesture:

> Advocates of allowing Montenegro to join NATO admit as much. The Senate hearing on admitting Montenegro to NATO was really just a Russia-bashing session. Not one word was said of how allowing Montenegro into NATO would advance our national security.
>   ...
>   Those who want to allow Montenegro into NATO believe that unless the whole world joins NATO, Russia will conquer the world. The truth is, as always, more complicated.